# Waiting for a service to be ready (Service Fabric)

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have four services running on Azure Service Fabric, but two of those 4 services depend on another one, is there a way to make a service initialization wait until another service announces it is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no ordering to service creation (services can be created at any time, not just during a deployment from your build machine), and what does it even mean for your service to be ready? From our perspective it means the Failover Manager found nodes that the service is able to run on and the code packages have been activated on those nodes. The platform doesn't know what your service code *does* though. From your perspective it probably means "when it's responding to my requests" otherwise it's not "ready," which can happen at any time during the service's lifetime for any number of reasons:

- Service was just deployed and its communication stack hasn't opened an endpoint yet
- Service instance/replica moved and its communication stack is spinning back up on a new node
- Service partition is in quorum loss and not accepting write operations
  etc.

This is an ongoing thing that your services need to be prepared to handle. If two of services can't do *any* work until they are able to talk to another service, then they need to poll for that service they depend on until it's available through an endpoint on that service that you define.